# iOS app clip with URL https://host/path does not match https://host/path/*

Tags: ios, apple-appclips

I set up an advanced app clip experience to be triggered by a URL in the form

> https://domain/pf

and I am actually expecting it to be triggered by a number of URLs in the form

> https://domain/pf/[uuid]

The app clip is correctly triggered by the exact "https://domain/pf" URL but not by the "https://domain/pf/[uuid]" URLs. Since the first URL triggers the app clip, I assume my .well-known/apple-app-site-association is correctly configured.

According to the original WWDC video on app clips (1) and to the official documentation (2) one should be able to catch all sub-URLs for an app clip experience.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks!

Alessandro

(1) https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10146/

(2) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/configuring_your_app_clip_s_launch_experience

Comment: What App Clip invocation method are you trying to use for your advanced App Clip? NFC tag? QR code?

Comment: I used QR codes

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of everyone who has the same issue, what I described above is now working.

I don't know the exact cause but I assume it's due to propagation of the information through the Apple servers.

The app clip (QR codes) started working after about 24 hours for my customers in the US and, after another day or so, the codes were also functioning in Europe.

So I guess the simple answer to my issue is "wait a little longer".

Answer (score 0):

That is correct the question is quite old but the underlying way of how app clip are propagated is still the same, it takes up to almost 48 hours to propagate the new advanced app clip configuration, you also should be able to track the status inside `Edit Advanced Experience` for each advanced configuration.